# Tkinter Treeview Column Text Justify Right

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Is there any way to cut the beginning of the text in a column value instead of cut the end in a treeview? The important part of the string in this table is at the end and I would like to show that before the beginning. In this example, I want the end of the column3 text to be shown instead of beginning first when there is not enough space for the column.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
treeview = ttk.Treeview(root)

treeview['columns']= ['header1', 'header2', 'header3']
treeview.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)

treeview.column('header1',anchor=E,width=10)
treeview.heading('header1',text='header1',anchor=CENTER)
treeview.column('header2',anchor=E,width=10)
treeview.heading('header2',text='header2',anchor=CENTER)
treeview.column('header3',anchor=E,width=5)
treeview.heading('header3',text='header3',anchor=CENTER)

treeview.insert(parent='',index='end',iid=0,text='',values=['col1', 'col2', 'DONTSHOWTHISFIRST-readllylongcol3text-readllylongcol3text-readllylongcol3text-IWANTTOSEETHISTEXT'])
treeview.insert(parent='',index='end',iid=1,text='',values=['col1', 'col2', 'DONTSHOWTHISFIRST-readllylongcol3text-readllylongcol3text-readllylongcol3text-IWANTTOSEETHISTEXT'])
treeview.insert(parent='',index='end',iid=2,text='',values=['col1', 'col2', 'DONTSHOWTHISFIRST-readllylongcol3text-readllylongcol3text-readllylongcol3text-IWANTTOSEETHISTEXT'])

Grid.columnconfigure(root,0, weight=1)
treeview.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew")
root.mainloop()
```

[Table of above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GytCh.png)

Comment: I suppose it's not possible to achieve such a behavior (like the behavior of cell textual content in an Open Office Spreadsheet) without manipulating (shortening by cutting the heading text away) the text itself. The anchor feature works as such, but not in case the text doesn't yet fit into the column. But ... maybe there is a not well known option??? Hard to be sure here ...